# Snakemake: Execute rule based on function with wildcards

Tags: python, wildcard, snakemake

I am making a pipeline with `snakemake`, and I use a `dataframe` as input just like this:

```
sample,fastq_1,fastq_2,replicate,paired_end  
A1,A1_R1.fq.gz,A1_R2.fq.gz,1,True  
A2,A2.fq.gz,,1,False
```

In the pipeline, I set sample as wildcards:

```py
samples = pd.read_csv('config/samplesheet_valid.csv', sep=",").set_index("sample", drop=False)
wildcard_constraints:
    sample_id = "|".join(samples.index)
```

and use a wildcards function to choose execute which run：

```py
def get_paired(wildcards):
    if samples.loc[wildcards.sample_id, "paired_end"]:
        return True
    else:
        return False

if get_paired:
    rule name_sort_bam_paired:
        input:
            bam_file = '{BASE_FOLDER}/bowtie2/filter/{sample_id}.flT.sorted.bam',
        output:
            sorted_bam = temp('{BASE_FOLDER}/bowtie2/filter/{sample_id}.clN.name.sorted.bam'),
            out_bam = temp('{BASE_FOLDER}/bowtie2/filter/{sample_id}.clN.bam'),
            out_sort_bam = '{BASE_FOLDER}/bowtie2/filter/{sample_id}.clN.sorted.bam'
        params:
            samtools = config['tools']['samtools'],
            bampe_rm_orphan = 'scripts/bampe_rm_orphan.py',
            python = config['tools']['python']
        threads: lambda wildcards: 10 if 10 < config['threads'] else config['threads']
        shell:
            """
            {params.samtools} sort -n --threads {threads} \
            -o {output.sorted_bam} \
            -T {wildcards.BASE_FOLDER}/bowtie2/filter/{wildcards.sample_id}.mLb.clN.name.sorted \
            {input.bam_file}

            {params.python} {params.bampe_rm_orphan} \
            {output.sorted_bam} {output.out_bam} --only_fr_pairs

            {params.samtools} sort --threads {threads} \
            -o {output.out_sort_bam} \
            -T {wildcards.BASE_FOLDER}/bowtie2/filter/{wildcards.sample_id}.clN.sorted \
            {output.out_bam}
            """
else:
    rule name_sort_bam_singled:
        input:
            bam_file = '{BASE_FOLDER}/bowtie2/filter/{sample_id}.flT.sorted.bam',
        output:
            out_bam = temp('{BASE_FOLDER}/bowtie2/filter/{sample_id}.clN.bam'),
            out_sort_bam = '{BASE_FOLDER}/bowtie2/filter/{sample_id}.clN.sorted.bam'
        params:
            samtools = config['tools']['samtools']
        threads: lambda wildcards: 10 if 10 < config['threads'] else config['threads']
        shell:
            """
            cp {input.bam_file} {output.out_bam}
            
            {params.samtools} sort --threads {threads} \
            -o {output.sorted_bam} \
            -T {wildcards.BASE_FOLDER}/bowtie2/filter/{wildcards.sample_id}.clN.sorted \
            {input.out_bam}
            """
```

But when I run this snkameake pipeline, all samples only run `name_sort_bam_paired`. But I want to run `name_sort_bam_paired` only when `get_paired` return `True`, and run `name_sort_bam_singled` when `get_paired` return `False`. How can I solution the problem? And I also want to know what causes this.

Answer (score 1):

I would use a single rule that does slightly different things depending on whether the input is single or paired. Something like:

```
rule name_sort:
    input:
        bam_file = '{BASE_FOLDER}/bowtie2/filter/{sample_id}.flT.sorted.bam',
    output:
        sorted_bam = temp('{BASE_FOLDER}/bowtie2/filter/{sample_id}.clN.name.sorted.bam'),
        out_bam = temp('{BASE_FOLDER}/bowtie2/filter/{sample_id}.clN.bam'),
        out_sort_bam = '{BASE_FOLDER}/bowtie2/filter/{sample_id}.clN.sorted.bam'
    params:
        is_paired = get_paired,
        samtools = config['tools']['samtools'],
        bampe_rm_orphan = 'scripts/bampe_rm_orphan.py',
        python = config['tools']['python'],
    threads: ...
    run:
        if params.is_paired:
            shell(r"""
            # Shell code for paired sorting
            {params.samtools} sort -n --threads {threads} \
            etc...
            """
        else:
            shell(r"""
            # Shell code for single sorting
            cp {input.bam_file} {output.out_bam}
            etc...
            """)
```